# Use -grep to count number of 6-letter words start with 'bar' and ends with 'i' or 'n'

Tags: grep, wc

I want to count the number of 6-letter words that start with 'bar' and end with 'i' or 'n'.

For example, given this file:

```
barxxi
barxxc
barxxn
barqwq
barovo
```

the output should be 2 (integer), since these lines match:

```
barxxi
barxxn
```

My code is the following, but it seems to be wrong:

```
grep -c 'bar??[ni]' /path/file.txt
```

Comment: I'm learning Unix and I have to accomplish this assignment by only using -wc or -grep.

Comment: You seem to be confusing shell globs (where `?` means "any single character") with regular expression syntax (where it's a repetition modifier).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I was doing a bigger edit when yours came. I rolled yours back in the hope that the final version is clear enough. Feel free to change the post if you think it can be improved.

Comment: @fedorqui No problem, your edits made it even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -o` which outputs only the matched text, multiple time per line if necessary.

```
grep -o '\<bar[^ ][^ ][ni]\>' /path/file.txt | wc -w
```

The `\<` and `\>` match the beginning and end of a word.
The `[^ ]` matches a non-space character.

Comment: yeah this is a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Replace your question marks `?` with periods `.` and your grep should work, as long as your input is only one word per line.

```
grep -c 'bar..[ni]' /path/file.txt
```

Comment: sure and why . instead of ? I thought ? was for a single char

Comment: The question mark character represents a single character in shell globbing syntax, not in regular-expression syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^bar.*[in]/ || $i ~ /[[:space:]]bar.*[in]/) { count++ }} END { print count }' filename
```

The above awk solution should also work. Taking account of multiple entries on each line, awk looks from the first space delimited entry in the file on each line to the last entry (NF) if then pattern matches against regular expressions with ~ and increments a count accordingly. Two if statements are created to take account or a beginning of line (^) and bar as well a space and bar. At the end, the count is printed to screen.

Comment: He has to accomplish this assignment by only using wc or grep, apparently